# li append function not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using blogger as my blogging platform. In my blog homepage, I create a function to grab all images from single post for each post (there are 5 posts in my homepage), then  append all images from single post to single slider, for each post.

This is my function script (I place it after `<body>` tag):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[

function stripTags(s, n) {
    return s.replace(/<.*?>/ig, "")
        .split(/\s+/)
        .slice(0, n - 1)
        .join(" ")
}

function rm(a) {
    var p = document.getElementById(a);
    img = p.getElementsByTagName("img").each( function(){
       $(".flexslider .slides").append($("<li>").append(this));
    });

    p.innerHTML = '<div class="entry-container"><div class="entry-content"><div class="entry-image"><div class='flexslider'><ul class='slides'></ul></div></div><div class="entry-header"><h1><a href="' + y + '">' + x + '</a></h1></div><p>' + stripTags(p.innerHTML, SNIPPET_COUNT) + '</p></div></div>'
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Then my variable, each post have single variable, different for each post based on it's ID:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>var x="Post Title",y="http://myblog.url/post-url.html";rm("p8304387062855771110")
```

My single post markup:

```
<span id='p8304387062855771110'></span>
```

The problem is, the append function in my script not work. Am I forget something in my code?

Comment: What does console say? Any errors?

Comment: `p.getElementsByTagName("img").each` No such method `.each()`.

Comment: So change to `$(p).find('img').each(...)`;

Comment: ...and your string literal being assigned to `p.innerHTML` is broken. Just lots of weird or broken code.

Answer (score 4):

Your jQuery/JavaScript is very ropey. There is no method `each` on a nodelist. Try not to mix jQuery/JavaScript up so much. And you might consider using a array/join on the html you want to insert to keep the line length readable. That way you might have noticed that your HTML quotes were not consistent.1

```
var $p = $('#' + a);

$p.find('img').each(function () {
  var html = $('<li>').append($(this))
  $('.flexslider .slides').append(html);
});

var html = [
  '<div class="entry-container"><div class="entry-content">',
  '<div class="entry-image"><div class="flexslider">',
  '<ul class="slides"></ul></div></div><div class="entry-header">',
  '<h1><a href="',
  y,
  '">',
  x,
  '</a></h1></div><p>',
  stripTags(p.innerHTML, SNIPPET_COUNT),
  '</p></div></div>'
].join('');

$p.html(html);
```

1 Personally I prefer single quotes for JS work and double quotes for HTML attributes and never the twain shall meet.

Comment: Highly questionable :) It's a classic English term.

Comment: Can someone confirm that it's `$("<li>").append($(this));` and not `$("<li>").append(this)` for me? I wasn't sure.

Comment: Both will work. In this case I don't think it's necessary to wrap it though

Comment: Both will work though it is really not necessary to have the lookup for $ and then invoke it, so `$("<li>").append(this)` should be used

Comment: @AnderMorales you have to put this code in your `rm()` function

Comment: @Spokey yes, I have do that, but now all image are missing from my homepage... I have also remove my `stripTags` function, but still the same results...

Answer (score 0):

```
I think <li> doesnt work try li like this:

 $(".flexslider .slides").append($("li").append(this));
```

Comment: Why do you think `$("<li>")` doesn't work? There are many things broken in the code, but that isn't one.

Comment: Here *li* is not a selector. `$("<li>")` will create a new *li* element.

Answer (score 0):

You could get rid of `type="text/javascript"` and `//<![CDATA[`, it is 2014, after all ;-)

Also, `.*?` is not what you mean.

```
<script>
function stripTags(s, n) {
    return s.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "") // Be careful with .*? : it is not correct
        .split(/\s+/)
        .slice(0, n - 1)
        .join(" ")
}

function rm(id) {
    var $p = $('#' + id);
    img = $p.find("img").each( function(){
       $(".flexslider .slides").append($("<li>").append(this));
    });

    p.innerHTML = '<div class="entry-container"><div class="entry-content"><div class="entry-image"><div class="flexslider"><ul class="slides"></ul></div></div><div class="entry-header"><h1><a href="' + y + '">' + x + '</a></h1></div><p>' + stripTags(p.innerHTML, SNIPPET_COUNT) + '</p></div></div>'
}
</script>
```

Comment: blogger template editor are a bit sensitive, removing `//<![CDATA[` will cause my code detected as not "well closed", exactly in `/<[^>]` code.